# Is there a way to identify which wire is L and which is N on an appliance (the electrical device itself, not the wall socket)?

Tags: wiring, appliances

I have a specific question but I thought it could also be made more generic. I have this device, a Fakir HQ1200 heater:

[image]

I am an idiot and disconnected the wires before taking a picture/marking them, and now I can't remember which wire goes where (except for the ground, which is the green/yellow wire which connects to the frame itself).

The wires in the picture, by the way, are the ones that go into the device itself (are part of the device). I have the wall side figured out, but I don't want to gamble on the device side.

Is there a way for me to identify which wire is the L wire and which one is the N wire without having the technical manual or wiring diagram for the device?

And if not, does anyone happen to know which wires are which on this specific model? Or otherwise, if these wires correspond to the wall socket standards in Germany (blue being N and white being L)?

Comment: WH: L1, BU: N, GR/YE: Ground

Comment: It's a German product, so it will probably follow German wiring standards. If you want to be sure, and find out if it matters how you connect L and N, why not ask the manufacturer [here](https://fakir.de/anfrage-formular?sInquiry=detail&sOrdernumber=6349006)?

Comment: @ocrdu thanks! I found their global website, but it's seriously broken.

Comment: In Germany the default colors for a 3-wire cable are: Green/Yellow = Earth, Brown = Live, Blue = Neutral. I would definitively ask the manufacturer, because the white wire is non-standard.

Comment: @AsafSitner: Better brush up on your German then ...

Answer (score -2):

If the wires are providing input then...

Take a multimeter... Switch to the highest AC reading option you have e.g 750v AC.

Now attach the negative probe to the ground and then with the positive probe touch each of the other wires, first white then blue. If you get a reading then its Live if you don't get a reading its Neutral.

Based on the research I have done the White would be Live and the Blue would be Nutral

Also this chart could help
[image]

Comment: The wires are not the wires that provide power to a device. The wires are the ones that go into the device from user terminals. It reads in the question.

Comment: @Justme Thanks, if you notice the first line of my answer I did mention if they provide input...